# Parralel.ForEach losing data

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have code that works too slowly:

```
DataTable result = GetDataTable();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var a = reader.Field<int>("a").ToString();
    var b = reader.Field<int>("b").ToString();
    var c = reader.Field<double>("c");
    var d = reader.Field<string>("d");
    var e = reader.Field<string>("e");

    DataRow datarow = result.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("A") == a && r.Field<string>("D") == d);

    if (datarow == null)
    {
        datarow = result.NewRow();
        datarow["A"] = a;
        datarow["D"] = d;
        datarow["E"] = e;
        result.Rows.Add(datarow);
    }
    datarow[b] = c;
}
return result;
```

and I change it to use `TPL`. Now it looks like:

```
var result = GetDataTable();
var concurrentCollection = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SomeClass>();

Parallel.ForEach(reader.ToDataTable().AsEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, row =>
{
    var a = reader.Field<int>("a").ToString();
    var b = reader.Field<int>("b").ToString();
    var c = reader.Field<double>("c");
    var d = reader.Field<string>("d");

    var values = concurrentCollection.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key.ToString() == $"{a}|{d}");

    if (values.Key == null)
    {
        var data = new SomeClass
        {
            Dictionary =
            {
                ["A"] = a;
                ["D"] = d;
                ["E"] = reader.Field<string>("e")
            }
        };
        values = new KeyValuePair<string, SomeClass>($"{a}|{d}", data);
    }
    values.Value.Dictionary[b] = c;

    concurrentCollection.AddOrUpdate(values.Key, values.Value, (key, oldValue) => values.Value);
});

foreach (var ins in concurrentCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Dictionary["D"]).ThenBy(x => x.Value.Dictionary["A"]))
{
    var datarow = result.NewRow();
    foreach (var key in ins.Value.Dictionary.Keys)
    {
        datarow[key.ToString()] = ins.Value.Dictionary[key];
    }
    result.Rows.Add(datarow);
}
concurrentCollection.Clear();
return result;
```

If I change `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1 the results of both code sections are the same.  But when I change value of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` the result data starts to differ. And the larger the value of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, the more the results are different.

Here is the converted results to `JSON` of **result** variable.

Part of results from first code section:

> [{
>       "A": "1010",
>       "1": "744",
>       **"2": "736"**,
>       **"3": "8"**,
>       "4": null,
>       "5": null,
>       "6": null,
>       "7": null,
>       "8": null,
>       "9": null,
>       "10": null,
>       "B": " Data",
>       "E": "0.4"
>   },...]

Part of results from second code section:

> [{
>       "A": "1010",
>       "1": "744",
>       **"2": null**,
>       **"3": null**,
>       "4": null,
>       "5": null,
>       "6": null,
>       "7": null,
>       "8": null,
>       "9": null,
>       "10": null,
>       "B": " Data",
>       "E": "0.4"
>   },...]

The number of mismatched objects in the result `JSON` array is different each start.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work using a `reader`. The reader is a cursor on your dataset and when you are hitting it multiple times from different threads you are going to end up scrambling your results like that. If it's database access that is slowing you down, you probably won't speed it up by going parallel like this.

Comment: reader.Read() is not thread safe.  It is a forward only cursor.

Comment: @developer if your query is slow, fix the query. If you want to combine data from multiple tables use a JOIN. Pushing all data to the far weaker client and trying to process it without benefit of indexing or parallelization (the database server *does* use parallelization and SIMD commands) will only make things *slower*

Comment: @developer where do `result` and `reader` come from? Same database, same server, different servers? What are you trying to do? The code looks like an attempt to find non-matching rows, typically performed by a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Maybe optimize your database indexes instead ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is no problem with receiving data from database. Problems starts when I try to transform (transpose) data from reader to result.

Comment: @developer your code isn't transposing, it performs a lookup. It does so in the slowest way possible, by searching all the data in a `DataTable`. If you put the keys into a dictionary it would be orders of magnitude faster. The numeric fields are converted to strings resulting in a very large number of temporary strings and essentially result in a memory leak. Leave them as integers and floats instead.

Comment: @developer convert your lookup data into a Dictionary or HashSet as Magnus shows and your code will go a *lot* faster. Keep the `a`, `A`, `d`, `D` etc fields as integers and your memory usage will go down, resulting in far fewer garbage collections

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you. I will try it a bit later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are going about this the wrong way. I assume the slow part is looking up the matching row in `result`. Try creating a dictionary with a key of the fields you need to find. Using a dictionary will have close to O(1) lookup.
 
If fields A and D are not unique together in `result` use a lookup instead. `ToLookup()` and pick the first row from the result of looking up the key (To be equal to the logic you have today)

```
DataTable result = GetDataTable();
var dic  = result.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r => new { A = r.Field<string>("A"), D = r.Field<string>("D")});
while (reader.Read())
{
    var a = reader.Field<int>("a").ToString();
    var b = reader.Field<int>("b").ToString();
    var c = reader.Field<double>("c");
    var d = reader.Field<string>("d");
    var e = reader.Field<string>("e");

    DataRow datarow;
    if(!dic.TryGetValue(new{A = a, D = d}, out datarow))
    {
        datarow = result.NewRow();
        datarow["A"] = a;
        datarow["D"] = d;
        datarow["E"] = e;
        result.Rows.Add(datarow);
        dic.Add(new{A = a, D = d}, datarow);
    }
    datarow[b] = c;
}
return result;
```

Comment: The dictionary is effectively an index. If the source for `result` and `reader` is the same database server a `LEFT JOIN` query on indexed rows would probably be a lot faster

Comment: I assume the op is trying to combine data from two different data-sources otherwise it would not make much sense.

Comment: even then, this isn't the most performant way to do it. Anyway, this code would probably be faster and use less memory if the `d`, `e` fields were read inside the `TryGetValue` block. Use ints as lookup keys instead of integers to avoid needless temporary strings and garbage collections. The question's code contains a lot of issues that can lead to memory leaks and big delays

Comment: I agree, but the main point would be to use a hashtable datastructure for  looking up the key instead of a loop.

Comment: @Magnus sorry, probably I misunderstood something, but dic is always empty.

Comment: It should only be empty if `result` is empty.

Comment: @Magnus but how `dic` should be filled? While loop add data to `result` , but `dic` is still empty.

Comment: You mean `result` starts as empty?

Comment: @Magnus yes, I mean this

Comment: In that case add to the dictionary also. See update.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class that overides equals and GetHashCode
Use a HashSet for O(1) lookup

```
    public static HashSet<Drow> GetRows()
    {
        HashSet<Drow> Drows = new HashSet<Drow>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int a;
        int b;
        double c;
        string d;
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
            a = rdr.GetInt32(0);
            b = rdr.GetInt32(1);
            c = rdr.GetDouble(2);
            d = rdr.GetString(3);
            Drow drow = new Drow(a, b, c, d);
            Drows.Add(drow); //it just will not add if it is a duplicat
        }
        return Drows;
    }
}
class Drow : object
{
    int ai;
    int bi;
    public string A { get; }
    public string B { get; }
    public double C { get; }
    public string D { get; }
    public Drow(int a, int b, double c, string d)
    {
        ai = a;
        bi = b;
        A = a.ToString();
        B = b.ToString();
        C = c;
        D = d;
    }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        // Check for null values and compare run-time types.
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        Drow r = (Drow)obj;
        return (A == r.A) && (B == r.B);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ai ^ bi;
    }
}
```